# Click on a certain part of the webpage only using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, click

How can I inject some Javascript into a UIWebView to click on a certain pixel (e.g. 100 pixels in from the left)?

I have the following code but I don't know the Javascript part:

```
NSString *ClickJSString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"ClickJavascript" ofType: @"txt"] usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:ClickJSString]];
```

The "ClickJavascript.txt" file is what I need to place the Javascript in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain it a little more?
Do you want to click a button or another HTML element?
Am I right, you like to trigger a click event on the page?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent
There is also a initMouseEvent...

Comment: I need it to click on an image. It's a fairly big image so it doesn't have to be exactly on the dot of 100px in from the left, but needs to be roughly...